# Setting the colspan of a cell using setAttributeNode throws an error in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

The following script throws the error `Member not found` in IE

```js
try {
  var dom = document.createElement("td");
  var attribute = document.createAttribute("colspan"); // rowspan has the same behavior
  dom.setAttributeNode(attribute);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
```

But the following snippets work fine:

```js
try {
  var dom = document.createElement("tr");
  var attribute = document.createAttribute("colspan");
  dom.setAttributeNode(attribute);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}

try {
  var dom = document.createElement("td");
  var attribute = document.createAttribute("style");
  dom.setAttributeNode(attribute);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
```

Is this a bug or is there a valid reason the error gets thrown. I couldn't find anything relevant.

Weird Interaction:

```js
var attribute = document.createAttribute("colspan");
var dom = document.createElement("td");
attribute.value = "5";
console.log(attribute.value); // "5"
try {
  dom.setAttributeNode(attribute);
} // throws error
catch (err) {}
console.log(dom.outerHTML); // "<td></td>"
console.log(attribute.value); // undefined
attribute.value = "5";
console.log(dom.outerHTML); // "<td colspan="5"></td>"
console.log(attribute.value); // "5"
```

**Note:** I am not asking how to set a `colspan` in a way that works on IE. I specifically want to know if the issue above is a bug.

Comment: Is your question really "is this a bug in IE" or is it really "how do I set a colspan on a `td` and have it work in IE"?

Comment: Okay, then this isn't an answer, but just FYI: You can use the [`colSpan` reflected property](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#attr-tdth-colspan) to set the colspan. That should work cross-browser. *(Reposted comment because I had a typo in the name and it had been more than five minutes. Doh!)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It looks like if the value of the attribute is a non-negative integer (i.e. `attribute.value = "0"`), as specified here in the [link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#attributes-common-to-td-and-th-elements) you posted, no errors get thrown.

Comment: That's weird, that was the first thing I thought of but it didn't work for me in IE11. Maybe I messed up my test. *Edit:* Nope, still fails for me with a `td` on IE11. Weird.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I must have had a typo when I run the test. It failed now. Current behavior is error gets thrown, the attribute still gets added to the element although it doesn't appear in the text format, once the value gets updated to a valid value after it has been added, then the attribute appears properly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Updated the question, added a new snippet to illustrate the weird behavior.

Comment: That is very weird. I'd call it a bug. :-)

Comment: it's a feature man

Comment: I have reproduced the problem on my side using your code, it seems that this is IE default behavior or Bug, I will feedback this issue to Microsoft, if get any response, I will tell you. Thanks for understanding. If you want to set the `rowspan` or `colspan`, I suggest you could use the setAttribute method: `var td = document.createElement("td");  td.setAttribute("colspan","2");`